# Swift 4: trying to load PDF from Data

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiviewcontroller

I am loading PDF from data to make a UIImage from it. I need to make it work from ios9 in swift 4.

here is my code:

```
    guard let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data), data.length) else { return nil}
    let cgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData)
    guard let pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(cgDataProvider) else { return nil }
```

but I have an error in first line: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer' with an argument list of type '(Data)'

I am looking for help how to rewrite it. I was trying with "withUnsafeBytes" but i was unable to make it work:

```
    let tempData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length: data.count)!
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        tempData.replaceBytes(in: NSMakeRange(0, data.count), withBytes: $0)
    }

    let bytes = data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, data.length)


    guard let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data), data.length) else { return nil}
    let cgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData)
    guard let pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(cgDataProvider) else { return nil }
```

Comment: Have you tried simply casting your Data to CFData? `let cfData = data as CFData`

Comment: try `guard let pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data as CFData)) else { return nil }`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
import PDFKit

let pdf = PDFDocument(data: data)
```

This way you can easily display a pdf inside a PDFView without the extra overhead of going through foundation. You can read all about `PDFKit` here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit